# bashrc argv escape space

Tags: bash, unix

I am working on a small bashrc function that will grep >= 10MB sized files/directories through du...

I have, however some problems with how it escapes spaces. It seems that `$1` breaks at a space even when trying to escape it with `\`.

I have tried also in the bashrc file to say:

`du -sch "$1"`

`du -sch $1`

`du -sch '$1'`

`du -sch $@`

- yet it still breaks at space even when escaped at input.

The bashrc entry:

```
dubig() { # greps after >= 10MB size in $DIR, else runs regular du -sch $DIR
if [ ! -z $1 ] ; then
    RE="(^[0-9]{2,}(M|\..*M$)|^[0-9]{1,}(G|\..*G$))";
    NM="-e \t- - No matches, printing normal output.";
    PR=$(echo $0 2&>/dev/null);
case $1 in
.)
    if du -sch $(pwd)/* |egrep "${RE}"; then echo ${PR}; else echo ${NM}; du -sch $(pwd)/*; fi
    ;;
*/)
    if du -sch $1* |egrep "${RE}"; then echo ${PR}; else echo ${NM}; du -sch $1*; fi
    ;;
/*)
    if du -sch $1/* |egrep "${RE}"; then echo ${PR}; else echo ${NM}; du -sch $1/*; fi
    ;;
*)
    if du -sch $1 |egrep "${RE}"; then echo ${PR}; else echo ${NM}; du -sch $1; fi
    ;;
esac
else
    echo -e "No path specified!\r\n1:\t$1\r\n@:\t$@"
fi
}
```

Output (no spaces in `$1`):

```
# dubig /var/root/
    - - No matches, printing normal output.
6.4M    /var/root/Library
0   /var/root/bla blea
4.0K    /var/root/test
4.0K    /var/root/test~
6.4M    total
```

Output (space escaped in `$1`):

```
# dubig /var/root/bla\ blea/
bash: [: /var/root/bla: binary operator expected
No path specified!
1:  /var/root/bla blea/
@:  /var/root/bla blea/
```

Output (space, non-escaped in `$1`):

```
# dubig /var/root/bla blea/
du: cannot access '/var/root/bla/*': No such file or directory
    - - No matches, printing normal output.
du: cannot access '/var/root/bla/*': No such file or directory
0   total
```

What am I doing wrong? As you can see it works fine so long as there are no spaces in `$1`.

However when escaping space upon input it seems to think that `$1` was not passed, when *NOT* escaping space upon input `$1` breaks at the space naturally.

Can't add relevant tags such as `bash-profile` due to missing reputation.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `bash-profile` per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double quotes around `$1` everywhere in your function, not just in the `du` command. Bash will perform parameter expansion and whitespace splitting on any unquoted string.

Single quotes are even stronger, so `'$1'` is simply the literal string consisting of a dollar sign and the number one.

Incidentally, your function basically only has two distinct cases, so it could be simplified a lot:

```
dubig() {
    if [ ! -z "$1" ] ; then
        case $1 in
            . | /* | */ ) set -- "$1"/* ;;
            *)  ;;
        esac 
        if du -sch "$@"| 
        egrep "(^[0-9]{2,}(M|\..*M$)|^[0-9]{1,}(G|\..*G$))" then 
            echo $0 2>/dev/null
        else
            echo -e \t- - No matches, printing normal output."
            du -sch "$@"
        fi
    else
        echo -e "No path specified!\r\n1:\t$1\r\n@:\t$@"
    fi
}
```

Comment: Ah so I had just forgotten to change `$1` to `"$1"` everywhere in the function. Thanks.

Comment: Very nicely done! Shortened down and everything. However it prints for instance `/var//folders` instead of `/var/folders` - I guess this is because upon input i added `/` on the end of `/var/` so it does have 3 cases, no? One which is current dir, another which does not end with `/` and one that does end with `/`.

Comment: So it should be `*/) set -- "$1"*;;` as the third case and then the rest as you have it. So it doesnt add another slash at the end.

Comment: Yeah, I regarded the extra slash as harmless but if you want to handle it separately, this should be the second case, and the current second case should be third.